# Вывод css стиля в php посредством echo

Tags: php, css, echo

В html-e понятно `<div id="...">`, в php echo `"<div style="sts2"><small><small>Включен</small></small></div>";` ничего не выдает вообще. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как бороться.

Comment: Спасибо сейчас попробую

Comment: Огроменнейшее вам спасибо, получилось

Comment: А нет, просто он не стал учитывать файл со стилями, все как было по дефолту черным, так и осталось, но стал отображаться.

Comment: в head-е <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="left_side.css" />
содержимое файла стилей

#sts2 { 
 color: #363030;
 text-shadow:#000 0px 1px 0px;  
 font-family: "Trebuchet MS";

Answer (score 1):

[[@hekut146](/users/28012/hekut146)](/users/28012/hekut146), потому что не `style`, а `class`.

а стили выглядят так:

```
.sts2 {
  color: #363030;
  text-shadow:#000 0px 1px 0px;
}
```

Comment: С точкой не работает, стоят #, с ними все отлично, вообщем проблему решил, нужно было просто в echo поставить ' а не ", т.е. - echo '<div id="sts2"><small><small>Включен</small></small></div>';

Comment: Вообщем всем спасибо суть я понял в чем была ошибка

Comment: @hekut146, настоятельно рекомендую почитать отличия `id` от `class`.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<div style=\"sts2\"><small><small>Включен</small></small></div>";
```

Comment: Вообщем всем спасибо суть я понял в чем была ошибка